# Программное заполнение полей на чужом сайте

Tags: javascript, html

Работаю с паспортными данными. Есть сторонний сайт, на который я должен выгружать эти данные. Там много полей `input`. Я должен их заполнять. Т.к. полей много, хотелось бы это дело автоматизировать. У сайта нет API, поэтому было бы прекрасно подключить к этому сайту скрипт, который будет заполнять поля ввода.

Вопрос: как подключить к сайту свой скрипт?

Comment: пишите плагин для браузера. сам не писал, не знаю как, но примерно представляю, что это можно оформить так: находите поля input, отсеиваете по общему class, id или name (если требуется) и после уже заполняете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использовал [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) и [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

```
npm install --save puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function inputData() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://адрес вашего сайта.com');
  const targetInput = '#value';//id нужного инпута
  await page.waitForSelector(targetInput);
  await page.type(targetInput, "ваши данные");
  const submitButton = '#submit';//id кнопки подтверждения
  await page.waitForSelector(submitButton);
  await page.click(submitButton);

  await browser.close();
}
```

[Тут пример](https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/341348/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/294664)

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 1):

Userjs — это скрипты на javascript, выполняемые браузером после загрузки каждой страницы, и позволяющие модифицировать её содержимое.

Скрипты Userjs можно подключить вручную в профиле браузера (в разных браузерах подключение немного отличается) или же воспользоваться плагинами на подобии Greasemonkey или Tampermonkey (это наиболее популярные, но есть и другие).

Есть очень много готовых решений и примеров, их можно найти на таких ресурсах как greasyfork.org openuserjs.org userstyles.org

Например вот так бы выглядит скрипт, который впишет в поле поиска строку "qwerty" на насем сайте ru.stackoverflow.com:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Demo
// @namespace    ru.stackoverflow.com
// @version      0.1
// @description  Demo
// @match        https://ru.stackoverflow.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    let searchField = document.querySelector("input.f-input.js-search-field");
    searchField.value = "qwerty";
})();
```